Does anyone know if research has been conducted about the Influence of peer presence on object choice? Specifically with elementary school children?
I need to create a two page research proposal for my perception class and it is very important that our research idea has not been used/published before. This is the extremely barebones idea I've come up with so far...
Exploring Individualistic Tendencies in Elementary School-Aged Children: The Influence of Peer Presence on Object Choice
A look into the individualistic tendencies of elementary school aged children
Research question: How does peer presence influence the object choice (candy or potato) of elementary school-aged children, and does it affect their demonstration of individualistic tendencies?
This experiment would be centered around the influence of peers and your choice of a stereotypically enjoyable choice object (candy) or an unusual object (potato) to flaunt your individualism.
Null Hypothesis: The same amount of children who were brought into a room on their own (zero peer observers) and given the choice of a potato or candy would grab the same amount of candy as students who were brought into the room as part of a group, choosing one of the two options in front of their peers.
Research hypothesis: A difference would be found in the proportion of candy vs. potato chosen between those students choosing without a peer in the room, and those students who have peers watching.

It's more important that you identify the related work that has been done. Experiments aren't run in a vacuum, they're supported by all the work already going on. I don't think it's appropriate to outsource your whole literature review to others, though. What have you found already? What are you basing your study on? It's also not necessary for every work to be completely novel in untouched territory; to support a theory it's often necessary to replicate a result many times, whether in different populations or with slightly different parameters, to verify the result generalizes.

I'd also think about different contingencies in your plan...what if all kids grab the candy and none in any group grab the potato? What would you conclude then?
